# How to define the density of random 3D points and plot it?

Tags: graphics3d, output, generative-art, version-7, random-process

The following code draws a random distribution of particles in 3D.  The Manipulate box allows to change a few parameters (number of particles, size of clusters, ...).  I would like to define the **local number of particles per unit volume** $V = \ell^3$, on a variable scale $\ell$, and plot it as level curves (i.e surfaces) in 3D.  How can this be done in Mathematica?

```
galaxies[p_, q_, r_] := Module[
    {pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {p, 3}]},
    pts = Nest[Join[#, {RandomChoice[#] + r RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 3]}] &, pts, q];
    pts
]

graph[p_, q_, r_] := Graphics3D[{RGBColor[{0.5, 0.4, 1.0}], PointSize[0.004], Point[galaxies[p, q, r]]}]

view[p_, q_, r_] := Show[{graph[p, q, r]},
    PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}},
    Boxed -> True,
    Background -> Black,
    ImageSize -> {700, 700},
    SphericalRegion -> True,
    Method -> {"RotationControl" -> "Globe"}
]

Manipulate[
    view[p, q, r],
    {{p, 500, "Number of clusters"}, 1, 1000, 1},
    {{q, 10000, "Number of galaxies"}, 0, 10000, 1},
    {{r, 0.05, "Scale"}, 0, 0.2, 0.001},
    ControlPlacement -> Bottom
]
```

The scale $\ell$ should be a variable, from a small value up to the full box size, say : $0.01 \le \ell \le 2$, that could be changed in another Manipulate box.  The idea is to plot the density of the particles in the box as a scalar function:
$$\tag{1}
\rho(x, y, z, \ell) = \frac{N(x, y, z, \ell)}{\ell^3},
$$
where $N(x, y, z, \ell)$ gives the total number of particles inside the cube of volume $V = \ell^3$, as a function of the cube center $\{x, y, z \}$ (with -1 < x, y, z < 1). I really don't know how to start to implement the idea, especially since the sampling volume should always stay inside the whole box of size $\ell_{max} = 2$ (with center located at $\{0, 0, 0 \}$).  The sampling near the edges of the whole box may also be a problem (maybe the random distribution should be defined on a box two times larger than the display box).

**EDIT:** The exact "microscopic" density of the $N$ particles can be defined using Dirac's deltas:
$$\tag{2}
\rho(x, y, z) = \sum_{k \,=\, 1}^N \delta (x - x_k) \, \delta (y - y_k) \, \delta (z - z_k).
$$
This density is 0 everywhere, except at the location of a particle.  We could then introduce the **averaged density** on a volume $\ell^3$ (around a point of coordinates $\{x, y, z\}$), by integration:
$$\tag{3}
\bar{\rho}_{\ell}(x, y, z) = \frac{1}{\ell^3} \int_{x - \ell/2}^{x + \ell/2} \int_{y - \ell/2}^{y + \ell/2} \int_{z - \ell/2}^{z + \ell/2} \rho(x, y, z) \, dx \, dy \, dz.
$$
That density could be called "fine grained" when $\ell$ is small, and "coarse grained" when $\ell$ is close to the size of the whole box.  In all cases: $0.0001 \le \ell \le 2$ (since the random distribution above is enclosed in a box of size $2$).

I should have stated this already from the start in my question, sorry about that.  The parameter $\ell$ should be a variable in a Manipulate box.  The function (3) is what I would like to calculate for my random distribution (code above), and plot as a 3D graphics (level curves or surfaces?).  Of course, we should get $\bar{\rho}_1(x, y, z) = N/8$ when $\ell = 2$.

Ideally, the density $\bar{\rho}_{\ell}(x, y, z)$ should be smoothed/interpolated to give some smooth level curves/surfaces in a plot, instead of ugly discontinuous jumps.  So how should I do this, with Mathematica?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this sounds like a job for [`SmoothKernelDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SmoothKernelDistribution.html)

Comment: @LukasLang, hmm, this sounds interesting.  Unfortunately, this function isn't implemented in my old Mma 7.0.

Comment: You can probably implement something similar by hand. All the relevant equations are given in the documentation I think. Two options that come to mind are to define a grid and add the contributions of each point into that grid (i.e. to effectively compute the distribution on a predefined grid), or to define a function as the sum of the different contributions (effectively the first equation from the documentation), and let the plotting function do the samplong itself.

Comment: I might certainly be not understanding the question but why would the average density change dependent on the size of the sampling unit?  (Whether that sampling unit be a box or a sphere or some other shape).  However, the density would certainly vary more among samples with smaller sized sampling units.

Comment: @JimB, the distribution is uniform on the largest scale, while it isn't at all on small scales.  So the average density is varying with the scale of the sampling.

Comment: I think you're making my point.  The "mean" density is constant.  The average density is not varying with the scale of the sampling.  It is the variability among sample units that depends on the scale of the sampling unit.  In your comment you use the term "distribution of density" which involves the variability.  But your question uses the term "mean density".  Do you not want to characterize the variability by scale rather than the mean by scale?

Comment: @JimB, I'm interested on the local density defined on a sampling and its location, and check how that density change with the size (and location) of the sampling. I'm not interested in the global density average. I'm interested in the *local* density, defined on a local sampling and some scale. And why the downvote?  I believe the question is perfectly clear and make sense.

Comment: I didn't downvote (yet).

Comment: To me this seems to be another question, in a series of related questions, used to leverage the mathematica community to help the OP solve a research project in cosmology, ie getting lots of work done for free. Hence -1 from me.

Comment: @HansOlo I think you bring up a good question for Mathematica Meta.  I'm pretty judgmental about the statistical aspects of questions on this site but helping someone with a research project "for free" doesn't bother me so much.

Comment: @HansOlo, well, that's not the case.  My initial project (about random points in space) is well finished.  But as it happens frequently with Mathematica coding, I then had other ideas to explore and experiment.  So it's not surprising that this question is apparently related to other questions I asked recently.  The density of particles seems like a natural thing to search after I saw the results of my previous project.  The density thing is just an interesting experimentation to do with Mathematica.

Comment: @cham Anyways the question seems more about the statistics rather than Mathematica. In any case, you can have a look at "counts in cells",  the correlation function and the fractal dimension, all related to what you want to do.

Comment: @HansOlo, the problem is I don't know how to code the idea with Mathematica, so the idea is more related to Mathematica than to statistics.  Given the random 3D points I get, how to compute the density of points in any cell of size $\ell$ in Mma?  That's the question!

Comment: Ok, I see. I already have some code to do exactly that. I'll post it in a sec.

Answer (score 2):

The following is an example based on a uniform distribution of points/galaxies, which can be adapted to any desired distribution. Also, some notes:

1. The code is given here only for educational purposes and several optimizations can be made.
2. Using `Nearest[]` is not the most efficient approach to calculate "counts in cells", ie the number of particles in growing spheres of radius $r$ around each galaxy. It is in fact rather inefficient.

First, let's make two populations of points

```
SeedRandom[12345]
data = RandomReal[{-2, 2}, {2000, 3}];
datarmin1 = Select[data, #.# <= 1 &];
```

For this approach (and all similar "counts in cells" methods), one needs either more overall galaxies (given by `data`) than then ones under study (given by `datarmin1`) or periodic boundary conditions (eg coming from an N-body sim).

Then we use `Nearest[]` to count the number $N(r)$ of points around each of the galaxies under study, within the larger sample:

```
r0 = 0.01;
rmax = 1.01;
dr = 0.05;
j`j = 0; SetSharedVariable[j`j];
ProgressIndicator[Dynamic[j`j], {0, (rmax - r0)/dr + 1}]
avNr = ParallelTable[{{r,N[Mean[Table[Length[Nearest[data, datarmin1[[i]], {Infinity, r}]], {i, 1,Length[datarmin1]}]]]}, j`j++;}[[1]], {r, 0.01, 1.01, 0.05},DistributedContexts -> Automatic] // AbsoluteTiming
```

Then, one may fit this to a power-law, ie $N(r)\sim r^D$ and determine that indeed a uniform distribution of galaxies has a fractal dimension of D=3:

```
ff = FindFit[avNr[[2]], a r^D2, {a, D2}, r]
```

and a plot of the result:

[image]

The code can be adjusted for other distributions, as the one given by the OP (which will have a different fractal dimension).

Comment: What is $r$ in your code?  Is that the cell size?

Comment: It's the radius of a sphere with the observer at the centre. This kind of calculations are mainly done in spherical coordinates.

Comment: I'll have to study this, since many of the commands are unknown to me.

Comment: Hans, please, see my edit, in my question.

Comment: I think my answer still stands, as the points are by default deltas. In this notation $r \simeq \ell$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach that I hope gets after your objective of

> I would like to define the local number of particles per unit volume
> V=ℓ3, on a variable scale ℓ, and plot it as level curves (i.e
> surfaces) in 3D.

```
(* Generate a universe *)
SeedRandom[12345];
galaxies[p_, q_, r_] := Module[{pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {p, 3}]}, 
  pts = Nest[Join[#, {RandomChoice[#] + r RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 3]}] &, pts, q];
  pts]
universe = galaxies[500, 10000, 0.05];

(* Number of cells in each dimension of a n x n x n grid to hold densities *)
n = 101;
(* Set a size of cube for the calculation of density *)
(* Galaxies within s in each dimension are included for the
   calculation of density for each grid cell *)
s = 0.05;
(* Array to hold the densities *)
d = ConstantArray[0, {n, n, n}];
(* Add each galaxy to the cells within s of each galaxy location *)
Do[{x, y, z} = universe[[i]];
 ix0 = Max[1, Ceiling[1/2 (1 + n - (x - s) + n (x - s))]]; 
 ix1 = Min[n, Floor[(1 + n - (x + s) + n (x + s))/2]];
 iy0 = Max[1, Ceiling[1/2 (1 + n - (y - s) + n (y - s))]]; 
 iy1 = Min[n, Floor[(1 + n - (y + s) + n (y + s))/2]];
 iz0 = Max[1, Ceiling[1/2 (1 + n - (z - s) + n (z - s))]]; 
 iz1 = Min[n, Floor[(1 + n - (z + s) + n (z + s))/2]];
 Do[Do[Do[
    d[[ix, iy, iz]] = d[[ix, iy, iz]] + 1/(2 s)^3, {ix, ix0, ix1}], {iy, iy0, iy1}], {iz, iz0, iz1}],
 {i, Length[universe]}]

(* Create array to hold coordinates and density for cell in d *)
(* This is for the required input format to ListContourPlot3D *)
density = ConstantArray[{0, 0, 0, 0}, n^3];
m = 0;
(* Convert cell indices to locations and add to the density array *)
Do[x = (-1 + 2 i - n)/(-1 + n); 
 Do[y = (-1 + 2 j - n)/(-1 + n); 
  Do[z = (-1 + 2 k - n)/(-1 + n);
   m = m + 1; 
   density[[m]] = {x, y, z, d[[i, j, k]]}, {i, n}], {j, n}], {k, n}]

(* Take a look at the resulting densities to consider *)
Histogram[density[[All, 4]], "FreedmanDiaconis", Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Density", "Count"}]
```

[image: Histogram of densities]

```
(* Choose a density of interest for contour *)
contourDensity = 5000;

(* ContourPlot3D *)
LBoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, MaxPlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image: 3D contour plot of galaxy density]

```
(* As a check on what is produced by ContourPlot3D, 
   show all of the grid points with a density of at least countourDensity *)
h = Select[density, #[[4]] > contourDensity &];
ListPointPlot3D[h[[All, {1, 2, 3}]], BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image: Points on grid where density exceeds 5000]